# Harmonic Oscillator

Tags: classical-mechanics

I have a model which can be written as

$$
\ddot \xi + r\dot \xi -\omega_0^2 \xi=0
$$

which is very similar to the [harmonic oscillator (HO)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_oscillator).

However, the coefficient of $\xi$ is negative and not positive as in the HO.

I'm interested in the oscillating behavior of the model. So my question is: 
Can I apply the conditions known for HO on this model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the coefficients are constant, 
$$\ddot \xi + r\dot \xi -\omega_0^2 \xi=0 \hspace{1 cm }(1)$$
will have a solution of the form  $\xi = e^{\lambda t}$, this will give you 
$$ \lambda^2 + r \lambda - \omega_0^2  = 0 \hspace{1 cm }(2)$$
The roots of equation of $(2)$ are 
$$ \lambda = \frac{-r \pm \sqrt{r^2 + 4 \omega_0^2}}{2} \hspace{1 cm }(3) $$
which gives you the solution of the form 
$$\xi = c_1 e^{\lambda_1} + c_2 e^{\lambda_2} \hspace{1 cm }(4)$$
since $\lambda$'s are real, it isn't oscillating which is not character of Harmonic Oscillator.

Depending on weather one of $\lambda$ is positive or both negative, the solution diverges exponentially or decays to rest.

Comment: Makes sense. Many thanks!